# Typescript Error: Cannot find name 'Promise'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

My project is currently on Ionic2 Beta 11 with Angular RC4. The problem is that that I need to chain as follow (the Plugin I use is returning a promise):

```
    this.dataService.loginWithFacebookNative()
    .then(
        result => {
            console.log(result)
            return result;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            if (error == 'cordova_not_available') return this.dataService.loginWithFacebook();

            return Promise.reject(error.message || error); // Here is the ts error
        })
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
        // Logic if login was a success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    })
```

Though the App itself is working as intended, Typescript is returning an error saying that

`[ts] Cannot find name 'Promise'`

I am not sure where to get Promise from.

Comment: There are several typings that offer a Promise, es6-promise and core-js are two that come to mind.  I know the Angular quick-start/tutorials use core-js.  I'm not sure what the Ionic framework uses, but you could start with one of those.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure where to get Promise from.

Quickest way is to compile with `lib` set to `es6,dom`.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option

## Alternatives

- bring in es6.promise.d.ts
- target es6 (definitely not what you want on current javascript engines). But usable if using another transpiler like babel (I recommend against such a complicated workflow).

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I tried running `tsc --target es5 --lib dom,es6
` and the same error still shows

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1. Add the typing from DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts
2. Select ECMAScript version 6 in TypeScript Build. This requires an ECMAScript 6 compliant javascript engine.

Comment: How would i do option 1?
I tries both `typings install dt~es6-promise --global --save` and 'npm install --save es6-promise' but its still showing a problem.

Comment: Is it an error from typescript build or at runtime? You can try to manually add the definition file to your project. Download es6-promise.d.ts an put it in {ProjectRoot}\Definition_Files\typings\es6-promise\es6-promise.d.ts (you can put it anywhere but this is where typings usually are)

Comment: Its an error that shows in my Editor (Visual Studio Code). But the code is working as intended though.

Comment: ok so just typescipt error. have you tried my solution from the comment above?

Comment: I did try it out using 
`typing install dt~es6-promise --global --save`
and
'npm install --save es6-promise'

but both did not work

Answer (score 0):

IF you are experience cannot find name 'Promise'., mostly you have changed some files in the base setup or may be you didn't finish the node package installation successfully. Angular2 doesn't use typings package anymore.

solution:

clone the following repository https://github.com/angular/quickstart
run npm install in the project directory and make sure it finish successfully
now copy and config your app project folders into the cloned new folder now this will work perfectly.